# Prevent SelectionChanged from evaluating during DataBinding operation

Tags: .net-4.0, datagridview

Have a situation where i need to suppress the `SelectionChanged` event logic until the `DataGridView` has completed Binding operations.

I have tried setting a Boolean flag variable to denote binding operations but it basically triggers the `DataBindingComplete` after each row is added.

Is there a way i can design a `Dirty` flag for the whole control that way the `SelectionChanged` event isnt triggered until the full `DataSource` has been bound to the `DataGridView`?